# Check for new SDK calls?

Tags: iphone

iOS development is now done using only the latest SDK.

Is there any way to search my code base for calls not present in older SDKs, generate warnings when compiling code that requires newer SDKs, or some other way to find where the code will fail on older iOS versions?

A workaround that broke compiling entirely would also be acceptable. This is not something I want to ship with, just something I want to do to verify that I've handled everything properly. The application *seems* to run on devices running earlier versions of iOS, but I'd like to be able to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this will do it...

Add this to your prefix:

```
#define __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED __IPHONE_3_1
```

Do **not** ship without removing this, though. In fact, you'll probably have to disable huge chunks of code to get your app to build this way. And even so, the coverage is nowhere near complete. But it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe that there is a good way to find new calls not available in older SDK's. It's something I've wanted for a while.

The best thing I know of is to test your app thoroughly on a device running the oldest version of the OS that you plan to support.

Comment: I actually remember reading a way to do this somewhere in Apple's forums, but their search engine is terrible. And it's also possible the way described *didn't actually work*.